# Error estimate for finite approximation of Hadamard gate from two rotations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-information, lie-algebra

I was teaching myself some fundamentals about quantum computing with [qiskit](https://qiskit.org) while I stumbled upon a challenge I am not able to solve. One [problem](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-ex/ex2.html) discusses how one can implement the Hadamard gate (in the $\sigma_z$ eigenbasis),

$$
H=\frac{\sigma_x+\sigma_z}{\sqrt{2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1\end{pmatrix},\tag{1}
$$

by using the state rotations,

$$
\begin{align}
R_x(\theta)=\exp\{i\theta\sigma_x/2\}, &&
R_z(\theta)=\exp\{i\theta\sigma_z/2\},\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$

wherein $\sigma_x,\sigma_y,\sigma_z$ are the [Pauli matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices). More precisely, we are given,

$$
H=\exp\left\{i\frac{\pi}{2}H+i\varphi\right\}\tag{3},
$$

which can be proven by using noting that the Hadamard operator $H$ is unitary and hermitian, therefore, $H^2=1$ which combined with the series representation of the exponential again gives us the Hadamard operator $H$ up to a global phase.

Furthermore, we are said that for,

$$
H_n=\left(R_x(\theta/n)R_z(\theta/n)\right)^n,\tag{4}
$$

we have $H_n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}H$ for the right choice of $\theta$.

When we visualize the Hadamard operator as rotation on the Bloch sphere, see [Visual interpretation, on the Bloch sphere, when Hadamard gate is applied twice](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/313959/visual-interpretation-on-the-bloch-sphere-when-hadamard-gate-is-applied-twice), Eq. (4) makes sense in that we do a small rotation around the $x$ axis, followed by a small rotation around the $z$ axis, and this repeated over and over.

Finally, there is the claim that the error reduces quadratic with $n$. **I would now like to give an explicit expression for the error in terms of $n$.**

#### Attempt 1: Rotation matrices

We can use the identity,

$$
\exp\left\{i\theta\sigma_i/2\right\}
=1\cos\frac{\theta}{2}+i\sigma_i\sin\frac{\theta}{2},\tag{5}
$$

to calculate,

$$
\begin{align}
R_x(\theta/n)R_z(\theta/n)
&=\left(1\cos\frac{\theta}{2n}+i\sigma_x\sin\frac{\theta}{2n}\right)\left(1\cos\frac{\theta}{2n}+i\sigma_z\sin\frac{\theta}{2n}\right)\\
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\frac{\theta}{2n} && i\sin\frac{\theta}{2n}\\
i\sin\frac{\theta}{2n} && \cos\frac{\theta}{2n}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\frac{\theta}{2n}+i\sin\frac{\theta}{2n} && 0\\
0 && \cos\frac{\theta}{2n}-i\sin\frac{\theta}{2n}
\end{pmatrix}\\
&=
\frac{1}{2}
\begin{pmatrix}
1+\exp\{+\frac{i\theta}{n}\} && 1-\exp\{-\frac{i\theta}{n}\}\\
-1+\exp\{+\frac{i\theta}{n}\} && 1+\exp\{-\frac{i\theta}{n}\}
\end{pmatrix},\tag{6}
\end{align}
$$

however, *I don't see how this can lead to the Hadamard gate*.

#### Attempt 2: Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula

The Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff (BCH) formula states,

$$
e^Xe^Y=e^{X+Y+\frac{1}{2}[X,Y]+\dots},\tag{7}
$$

for non-commutative $X,Y$ in a Lie algebra. The Pauli matrices form a Lie algebra, henceforth,

$$
R_x(\theta/n)R_z(\theta/n)
=\exp\left\{\frac{i\theta}{2n}\sigma_x\right\}\exp\left\{\frac{i\theta}{2n}\sigma_z\right\}
=\exp\left\{\frac{i\theta}{2n}(\sigma_x+\sigma_z)+i\frac{\theta^2}{4n^2}\sigma_y+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)\right\},\tag{8}
$$

where we have used $[\sigma_x,\sigma_z]=-2i\sigma_y$. Using the exponential series representation and neglecting higher orders of $1/n$, we find,

$$
R_x(\theta/n)R_z(\theta/n)=1+\frac{i\theta}{2n}(\sigma_x+\sigma_z)+\frac{i\theta^2}{4n^2}\sigma_y-\frac{\theta^2}{4n^2}(\sigma_x+\sigma_z)^2+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right). \tag{9}
$$

By noting $(\sigma_x+\sigma_z)^2=1+\{\sigma_x,\sigma_z\}+1=2$, we can simplify Eq. (5) to,

$$
R_x(\theta/n)R_z(\theta/n)
=1+\frac{i\theta}{2n}(\sigma_x+\sigma_z)+\frac{i\theta^2}{4n^2}\sigma_y-\frac{\theta^2}{2n^2}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right).\tag{10}
$$

From my dark analysis days, I remember that,

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n=e^x.\tag{11}
$$

If I assume $n\gg1$ and multiply out the powers while neglecting higher orders of $1/n$ I find,

$$
\begin{align}
H_n
&=(R_x(\theta/n)R_z(\theta/n))^n\\
&=\left(1+\frac{i\theta}{2n}(\sigma_x+\sigma_z)\right)^n+\frac{\theta^2}{4n^2}(i\sigma_y-2)+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)\tag{12}\\
&=H+\frac{\theta^2}{4n^2}(i\sigma_y-2)+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right),\tag{13}
\end{align}
$$

however, *I don't feel very comfortable with the last step as we keep higher-order $1/n$ terms for the first term in Eq. (12) but we drop them for the second (and higher) terms in Eq. (12). In addition, we take the limit $n\to\infty$ on the first term of Eq. (12) to recover the Hadamard operator $H$ but we don't do the same for the second term of Eq. (12) to arrive at Eq. (13).*

If Eq. (13) is correct, we can check Eq. (3) to find that $\theta=\pi/\sqrt{2}$.

#### Error of the measurement

Given an initial (qubit) state,

$$
\vert 0\rangle=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix},
$$

the [qiskit](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-ex/ex2.html) article proposes to use,

$$
E=\vert\langle0\vert H_nH\vert0\rangle\vert^2-1,\tag{14}
$$

as an error estimate. For $E\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$, i.e. there would be no error because of $H^2=1$. For finite $n$ Eq. (13) would give us,

$$
\begin{align}
E
&=\left\vert\langle0\vert\frac{\pi^2}{8n^2}(i\sigma_y-2)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}H\vert0\rangle\right\vert^2\\
&=\left\vert
\begin{pmatrix}1 && 0\end{pmatrix}\frac{\pi^2}{16n^2}\begin{pmatrix}-2 && 1\\-1 && -2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 && 1\\1 && -1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}
\right\vert^2\\
&=\left(\frac{\pi}{4n}\right)^4.\tag{15}
\end{align}
$$

Comparing the expression for the error in Eq. (15) with a simulation:

[image: Simulation]

We find that $(\pi/4)^4\approx0.38$, $(\pi/8)^4\approx0.024$. *Thus, something is wrong.*