# How do I visualize a stepwise rotation on the Bloch Sphere using $SO(3)$ and $SU(2)$?

Tags: quantum-information, computational-physics, rotation, software, bloch-sphere

Searching for an implementation (that helps me to understand how $SO(3)$ and $SU(2)$ relate to each other) I came across this interesting question [Visual interpretation, on the Bloch sphere, when Hadamard gate is applied twice](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/313959/visual-interpretation-on-the-bloch-sphere-when-hadamard-gate-is-applied-twice) where qutip is utilized. However my question is more fundamental.

Using qutip too, I implemented a rotation of a Qubit on a Bloch Sphere using $SO(3)$ as follows:

```
import qutip as qt
from qutip.qip.operations import rx
import numpy as np

def to_spherical(state):
    r0 = np.abs(state[0])
    ϕ0 = np.angle(state[0])
    r1 = np.abs(state[1])
    ϕ1 = np.angle(state[1])
    r = np.sqrt(r0 ** 2 + r1 ** 2)
    θ = 2 * np.arccos(r0 / r)
    ϕ = ϕ1 - ϕ0
    return [r, θ, ϕ]

def to_cartesian(polar):
    r = polar[0]
    θ = polar[1]
    ϕ = polar[2]
    x = r * np.sin(θ) * np.cos(ϕ)
    y = r * np.sin(θ) * np.sin(ϕ)
    z = r * np.cos(θ)
    return [x, y, z]

def rn_so3(state, theta, phi, delta):
    rn_mat = qt.Qobj(
        [[np.cos(delta/2) - (0+1j)*np.cos(theta)*np.sin(delta/2),
          -(0+1j)*np.exp(-(0+1j)*phi)*np.sin(delta/2)*np.sin(theta)],
         [-(0+1j)*np.exp((0+1j)*phi)*np.sin(delta/2)*np.sin(theta),
          np.cos(delta/2) + (0+1j)*np.cos(theta)*np.sin(delta/2)]]
        )
    r_state = (rn_mat*state)*(rn_mat*state).dag()
    return(r_state)

b = qt.Bloch()
b.clear()
b.make_sphere()

states = []
points = []

alpha = 1/np.sqrt(2)
beta = 1/np.sqrt(2)
s = np.array([alpha,beta])
state = qt.Qobj(s)
states.append(state)

Ψ = [complex(alpha, 0), complex(beta, 0)]
polar = to_spherical(Ψ)
pnt = to_cartesian(polar)
points.append(pnt)

rotated = state
for i in range(0,10):
    rotated = rn_so3(rotated, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2)
    pnt = [(qt.sigmax()*rotated).tr(), (qt.sigmay()*rotated).tr(), (qt.sigmaz()*rotated).tr()]
    states.append(rotated)
    points.append(pnt)

b.add_states(states)
np_points = np.array(points)
b.add_points([np_points[:,0], np_points[:,1], np_points[:,2]])
b.show()
```

The corresponding output looks as follows:

[image]

***My question:***
Can I achieve the same output using the $SU(2)$ group and coordinate transformations?

I found also the formula for the rotation around an axis on the Bloch Sphere with an angle $\theta$ that looks as follows:

$$R_A(\theta)=\cos\frac{\theta}{2}\sigma_I-i\cdot\sin\frac{\theta}{2}(x_A\sigma_x+y_A\sigma_y+z_A\sigma_z)$$ which I tried to implement too but didn't output the desired rotation.

My trial looks as follows and I am trying to refer to this document ["Lecture notes: Qubit representations and rotations](https://www.phys.hawaii.edu/%7Eyepez/Spring2013/lectures/Lecture1_Qubits_Notes.pdf)":

```
def rn_su2(θ, ϕ):
    return (np.sin(θ)*np.cos(ϕ)*qt.sigmax() + np.sin(θ)*np.sin(ϕ)*qt.sigmay() + np.cos(θ)*qt.sigmaz())

b = qt.Bloch()
b.clear()
b.make_sphere()

states = []
points = []

alpha = 1/np.sqrt(2)
beta = 1/np.sqrt(2)
s = np.array([alpha,beta])
state = qt.Qobj(s)
states.append(state)

Ψ = [complex(alpha, 0), complex(beta, 0)]
polar = to_spherical(Ψ)
pnt = to_cartesian(polar)
points.append(pnt)

rotated = state
for i in range(0,10):
    #
    # Here seems to go something wrong
    #
    rotated = rn_su2(0.2*i, 0.3*i)
    states.append(rotated)

    #polar = to_spherical(rotated)
    #pnt = to_cartesian(polar)    
    points.append(pnt)

b.add_states(states)

np_points = np.array(points)
b.add_points([np_points[:,0], np_points[:,1], np_points[:,2]])
b.show()
```

Here I have some fundamental error and would appreciate any help or hint.

***Update 2022-03-19:***
I implemented the $SU(2)$ rotation according the useful hint in the comment. It looks better, but unfortunatelly the state lies not on the Bloch Sphere anymore:

```
def rn_su2(θ, state, nx, ny, nz):
    Ψ = [state.data[0,0], state.data[1,0]]
    arr = to_spherical(Ψ)
    s_θ = arr[1]
    s_ϕ = arr[2]
    M_q = np.sin(s_θ)*np.cos(s_ϕ)*qt.sigmax() + np.sin(s_θ)*np.sin(s_ϕ)*qt.sigmay() + np.cos(s_θ)*qt.sigmaz()
    U_n = qt.qeye(2)*np.cos(θ/2) -1j*(nx*qt.sigmax()+ny*qt.sigmay()+nz*qt.sigmaz())*np.sin(θ/2)
    r_state = U_n*M_q*U_n.dag()
    return r_state
```

***Update 2022-03-20:***
After fixing the $SU(2)$ rotations code it looks good and correct. Now I'm just struggling with the actual question: what angles do I need to use so that both plots (vertex sequences) look the same? In the [$SO(3)$ implementation](https://github.com/Sultanow/quantum/blob/main/bloch_sphere/rotate_so3.ipynb) case I used `rotated = rn_so3(rotated, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2)` and to get an almost same looking picture, by trial and error, I obtained for the [$SU(2)$ implementation](https://github.com/Sultanow/quantum/blob/main/bloch_sphere/rotate_su2.ipynb):

```
rotated = rn_su2(0.05, rotated, 1, 0, 0)
rotated = rn_su2(0.02, rotated, 0, 1, 0)
rotated = rn_su2(0.2, rotated, 0, 0, 1)
```

The comparative figures are as follows:

[image]

Comment: In that code the line `rotated = rn_su2(0.2*i,0.3*i)` looks strange. Formula (25) in the lecture notes that you linked to shows how to rotate using $SU(2)$. This is also explained in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation).

Comment: Thank you for this hint. Yes - you are correct: the line of code, you highligted, is the suspect one. It would be great to know how to incorporate formula $(25)$, that is $M_{q'}=U_{\hat n}(\theta)\cdot M_q\cdot U_{\hat n}^{T}(\theta)$, into qutip. I see that I have to implement formula $(24)$ first. Will try it.

Comment: You should check that your code obeyes the following: 1. A point on the Bloch sphere is a vector in $\mathbb R^3$ with length one. 2. As such it can be represented by a pure quaternion (a quaternion with real part zero). $M_q$ is that pure quaternion in matrix form. 3. $U_n$ is a unit quaternion (has length one). I have done many such python implementations myself and the rotation always worked as expected. In particular, the rotated pure quaternion did not change its length.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now we are only a small step away from the answer of the question what angles we have to use so that both images look the same. It would be great if you may unveil this.

Comment: In the Wikipedia link I gave in the first comment it is explained how the rotation angle and axis must be built into the unit quaternion $U_n$. In short : the real part of that unit quaternion is $\cos\frac{\theta}{2}$ where $\theta$ is the rotation angle we know from the $SO(3)$ matrix.